# How to receive data/notifications in a Firebase and Cordova app

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

Let's say I have a chat app built with Cordova, that uses Firebase as the backend.

When the app is running, the app can listen for changes on a node and update accordingly (which also uses up 1 connection).

However, I want the app to be able to receive notifications while the app is closed (i.e. a new message is received).

I had considered leaving the app running in the background, but that means the app is consistently using a concurrent connection in firebase, and that would not be such a good idea.

How would I go about doing this? Is there a plugin that will help facilitate this? I am using just plain JavaScript for experimentation, so I'm not using Angular or react or anything like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Cloud Messaging https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/ can help you with this.

FireBase has a sample code which resembles your use-case a bit.
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Their use-case is

> This sample demonstrates how to send a Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) notification from a Realtime Database triggered Function. The sample also features a Web UI to experience the FCM notification.

Without having worked with Cloud Messaging yet, I think you could do the following

1. Make a onWrite trigger function for your database chat nodes. "This will trigger whenever a new message is created"
2. Send a cloud message to the chat participants if the app is not already open